# Why session is not persistent?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to implement localization in my laravel 4 app, its straightforward:

I submit locale to the method:

```
class LanguageController extends \BaseController
{
    public function chooser(){

        Session::set('locale',Input::get('locale'));
        return Redirect::back();

    }
}
```

but, I keep getting session value un-changed, any idea?
Is there a recommended laravel package to handle sessions?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
App::setLocale(Input::get('locale'));
```

You can then get the locale using `App::getLocale()`

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason, after Redirect::back(); , in the view, {{App::getLocale()}} will result in no change, and I keep getting the same locale, why?!

Comment: Can you show me where do you use App::setLocale()? And do you use it anywhere else?